# Want to connect to iCloud caldav server and add an event, preferably from PHP

Tags: php, icloud, icalendar, caldav

I am trying to get a server script back end to connect to an iCloud calendar and add an event to a certain calendar.
I have found a scrip that can connect to the iCloud server and scrape all the right info for URL's needed etc but can find no example or documentation on adding or at least syncing an event from a web based script, ideally php to an iCloud server caldav calendar.

This is a script that can connect and get the necessary URLS
http://icloud.niftyside.com/

But am struggling after that.
Anyone know of a simple way to get PHP to fire an event into it??

Comment: refer the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111887/how-to-import-icloud-contacts-in-php/16412776#16412776