# How to import iCloud contacts in php

Tags: php, icloud

How to import contacts from iCloud using a iCloud API or any other method which use PHP as server side language. I know there iCloud support cardDav through which we can import iCloud contacts but how? it still a question for me

If any one have an idea it will be very helpful

Comment: I find a link to get calDAV and cardDav url which would be helpful in accomplishing the task I am exploring the ways I can do some trick to import the contacts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659233/want-to-connect-to-icloud-caldav-server-and-add-an-event-preferably-from-php?rq=1

Comment: try this for above download   //CardDAV URL
  $card_request="<A:propfind xmlns:A='DAV:'>
        <A:prop>
         <A:allprop/>
        </A:prop>
       </A:propfind>";

  $cardserver = str_replace('caldav', 'contacts', $_POST['server']);
  $cardurl = $cardserver."/".$userID."/carddavhome/card/";
  
  $response=simplexml_load_string(doRequest($user, $pw, $cardurl, $card_request));
  
  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($response);
  echo "</pre>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCloud support cardDAV client/server protocol through which we can make a request to iCloud server and get the saved contacts from iCloud.

To implement cardDAV client/server protocol one need to use third party API and there is very useful and easy to use API available to accomplished this task using **Roundcube-CardDAV** you  can download this library using [this](https://github.com/graviox/Roundcube-CardDAV) link.

To use **Roundcube-CardDAV** you need to use **PEAR.php** file.

RoundCube-CardDAV returns contacts in Vcard format so need to parse it also which can be done using **Contact_Vcard_Parse** class found by [here](http://pear.php.net/package/Contact_Vcard_Parse/download).

You also need iCloud server on which you would make request so it is **https://p01-contacts.icloud.com/1603801586/carddavhome/card/** where p01 is server number goes further like p02,p03,p04...p06 etc

Comment: You don't need the specific iCloud server, you can just use contacts.icloud.com w/o any prefix. To discover the DAV collection which hosts your address book, use 'curl -u "$LOGIN" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Depth: 0" -X PROPFIND --data "<propfind xmlns='DAV:'><prop><current-user-principal/></prop></propfind>" https://contacts.icloud.com/
'. This gives you back the principal URL (representing the account), which you can then use to find the address book (ask the URL you got for the 'addressbook-home-set' CardDAV property)